# Opposite of \parindent

Tags: indentation

I want to do the opposite of normal paragraph indentation, meaning:

1. Have no indent on the first line of each paragraph, but
2. Indent each subsequent line in the paragraph.

Currently I'm using the command `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to accomplish (1), but what is the command for (2)?

Comment: It seems to me that you want a negative indentation.

Comment: @egreg But a negative indentation will result in the first line extending into the margin.  I assume that that was probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @A.Ellett Why not? Just define titles to also be in the margin and push the margin a bit to the right. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'd be interested in seeing a solution along the lines your suggesting.  It's a very simple idea.  I kind of really like it.  But what about things like math equations or other matter that you might normally want centered on the page.  Are there other  clever tricks to get those effects too?  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A combination of `\leftskip` and `\parindent` can achieve, I think, what you seek (that is, having the hanging indent persist beyond a single paragraph).  Then reset them when you are done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0em
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\leftskip=2em
\parindent=-2em
\lipsum[2-4]
\leftskip=0em
\parindent 0em
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can set the stuff off in its own brace-delimited group.  Then, you don't have to reset them at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent=0em
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
{
\leftskip=2em
\parindent=-2em
\lipsum[2-4]
}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to this that `\hangindent` doesn't have? Otherwise, it seems like the perfect solution!

Comment: @jamaicanworm I am not aware of a particular disadvantage of this solution, but then again, I can't claim to be ultimately versed on the topic either.  And, as you are already aware, this approach persists across paragraph boundaries.

Answer (score 38):

You could consider using `\hangindent`

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\hangindent=2em
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

In conjunction with `\hangafter` you can get various interesting effects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\hangindent=2em%%
\hangafter=3\relax
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Combining positive and negative values to `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` allows you to create various *holes* in your paragraphs:

```
\hangindent=-2in%%
\hangafter=3\relax
\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{1cm}

\hangindent=-2in%%
\hangafter=-3\relax
\noindent
\lipsum[2]
```

[image]

Another command worth considering is `\parshape`:
The syntax of `\parshape` is

```
 \parshape <number of lines>
           <indent dimension> <line width>
           <indent dimension> <line width>
           <indent dimension> <line width>
           <indent dimension> <line width>
```

Here there are as many `<indent dimension> <line width>` pairs as `<number of lines>`.  The effect of `\parshape` ends at the end of the paragraph regardless of how many lines the paragraph contains.  If there are more lines to the paragraph than provided to `\parshape` the last `<indent dimension> <line width>` pair applies to the remainder of the paragraph.

```
\parshape 2
          0pt \textwidth
          2em \dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
\noindent
\lipsum[1]
```

[image]

With `\parshape` and a bit a creativity, you can create all sorts of paragraph shapes:

```
\parshape 11
          0pt \textwidth
          1em \dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
          2em \dimexpr\textwidth-4em\relax
          3em \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax
          4em \dimexpr\textwidth-8em\relax
          5em \dimexpr\textwidth-10em\relax
          4em \dimexpr\textwidth-8em\relax
          3em \dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax
          2em \dimexpr\textwidth-4em\relax
          1em \dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
          0em \textwidth
\noindent
\lipsum[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the wonderfully detailed answer! Is there any way to make `\hangindent` work for all subsequent paragraphs (even ones that are separated by a newline in the text editor)?

Comment: @jamaicanworm I was anticipating that question.  I'm not quite sure how to do this.  You would have to do some magic involving `\everypar`.  But depending on what's going on in your document, `\everypar` is easily overwritten and you lose your formatting.  I would suggest that you ask a second question about how to apply your for to all paragraph.

Comment: @jamaicanworm You can do this by make LaTeX execute the `\par` primitive inside a group. This may break with more complex constructs, but try `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\@setpar{\begingroup\@@par\endgroup}
\makeatletter`

Comment: @Joseph, how does this make changes to paragraph shape persistent? Please explain.

Comment: Of course this is incompatible with all list constructions in LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know :-) Finish `l3galley`, make compatible list structures, ... and all will be well!

Comment: @alexis TeX clears `\parshape` and relates stuff when you execute the `\par` primitive. This clearing obeys grouping, so I've used `\par` the primitive inside a group. LaTeX saves the primitive as `\@@par`, and uses `\@setpar` to manage the meaning of the `\par` token. As egreg notes, the LaTex2 list implementation also needs to alter the meaning of the `\par` token. A long-term way around this is a more 'managed' approach to the entire area, which `l3galley` offers but at the cost of breaking much LaTeX2e code.