# How to make some text take up the same amount of space as other text

Tags: spacing

I want some text to take up the same amount of space as other text.  For example, in the script below, how do I make `BOB` take up the same amount of space as `MELISSA` so the beginning of their dialogue lines are aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
BOB Hello, Melissa.
MELISSA Hello, Bob.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something of the style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\blob}
\settowidth{\blob}{MELISSA}
\begin{document}
\makebox[\blob][l]{BOB} Hello, Melissa.

\makebox[\blob][l]{MELISSA} Hello, Bob.
\end{document}
```

will work if the dialogs are less than one line. If the dialogs could be longer, you could try to use hanging paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\newlength{\blob}
\settowidth{\blob}{MELISSA } %% longest with space
\newcommand{\start}[1]{%
  \parindent0pt
  \everypar={\hangpara{\blob}{0}}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\blob][l]{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\dstop}{%
  \parindent0pt
  \everypar={}
}
\begin{document}
\start{BOB} Hello, Melissa. 

\start{MELISSA} Hello, Bob. Speaking  Speaking  Speaking  Speaking
Speaking  Speaking  Speaking  Speaking  Speaking  Speaking  Speaking
Speaking

And more speaking speaking speaking...

\dstop

Normal paragraph here 

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image: Example]

You can easily modify `\start` and `\dstop` macros to change fonts, add skips etc. that can make the dialogs easier to read.

Comment: I'm using the command `\leftskip=16pt \parindent=-16pt` at the beginning of my document to create that "hanging" indent, without needing to repeat anything (like your command `\start`), as recommended by this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140244/9757 Is there a way to "get" the length of `MELISSA`, so I could do something like `\leftskip=\length{MELISSA}`?

Comment: @jamaicanworm Either Rmano or me are suggesting you the macro `\settowidth` (probably with some corrections of a space).

Comment: Figured it out: I can do `\leftskip=\blob \parindent=-blob`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you need this for a drama-like typesetting. Then probably one of specialized packages will be useful, for example `dramatist`, `drama` or `play`.

But if you only need to put `BOB` in the box of dimension of `MELISSA`, you can do:

```
\newlength{\melis}
\settowidth{\melis}{MELISSA}
\makebox[\melis][l]{BOB}
```

Comment: If one loads the package [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) and defines the macro `\newcommand\BOB{\makebox[\melis][l]{BOB}}\xspace`, one could write `\BOB` whenever it's necessary to typeset the word BOB to width of the word MELISSA. The `xspace` macro makes it unnecessary to remember to insert `\` after `\BOB` to get a word space.